# Prepare of SQL query for Informix DB

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, informix

We have 3 columns `rx, dateTime and tx` . one rx can have multiple tx .

Table is table1

#### Case 1:

if `rx` has both type of  `tx < 8 and tx> 8` then select complete row for the `tx<8`.

#### Case 2:

if `rx` has only `tx>8` then select the only one that is latest `tx`.

Can anyone please assist?

Below is the Example:

**Note** higher the datetime value determine latest

```
rx  tx  date time
1   9   24
1   7   23
1   4   23
1   10  26
2   10  4
2   14  8
2   18  20
2   9   19
```

Expected result:

```
rx  tx  datetime
1   7   23
1   4   23
2   18  20
```

Db is Informix
Note:-no action for tx <8 and there is no data for tx=8

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your output based on that. Also mention the database name/version

Comment: ex..

Note higher the datetime value determine latest 

rx#   tr#  datetime#(just example)

1 4  2  
1 2  3
1 10  2
1 7  23
1 9  2
1 10  25
2 24  24
2 13  22 
2 55  26
================================

expected result is:

rx#   tr#  datetime#(just example)
1 10  2
1 9  2
2 55  26
=================================

Comment: Database is Informix

Comment: What should be the behavior if `rx` has only `tx < 8`? And if `tx = 8`?

Comment: Richord,no action for tx <8 and there is no data for tx=8

Answer (score 1):

Let's prepare the test case you've given:

```
[infx1210@tardis tmp]$ dbaccess -e demo test.sql

Database selected.

CREATE TABLE table1 (
        rx                      SMALLINT,
        tx                      SMALLINT,
        date_time       SMALLINT
);
Table created.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 9, 24);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 7, 23);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 4, 23);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 10, 26);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 10, 4);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 14, 8);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 18, 20);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 9, 19);
1 row(s) inserted.

SELECT * FROM table1;

    rx     tx date_time

     1      9        24
     1      7        23
     1      4        23
     1     10        26
     2     10         4
     2     14         8
     2     18        20
     2      9        19

8 row(s) retrieved.

Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis tmp]$
```

> **Case 1:** if `rx` has both type of  `tx < 8 and tx > 8` then select complete row for the `tx < 8`.

```
SELECT  t1.rx, 
        t1.tx, 
        t1.date_time
FROM    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  rx, 
                MAX(tx) AS max_tx, 
                MIN(tx)  AS min_tx 
        FROM    table1 
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t2 ON t1.rx = t2.rx
WHERE   8 BETWEEN t2.min_tx AND t2.max_tx
        AND t1.tx < 8;
```

> **Case 2:** if `rx` has only `tx > 8` then select the only one that is the latest `tx`, hence the higher `date_time`

```
SELECT  t1.rx, 
        t1.tx, 
        t1.date_time
FROM    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  rx, 
                MIN(tx) AS min_tx,
                MAX(date_time) AS latest_tx
        FROM    table1 
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t2 ON t1.rx = t2.rx
WHERE   t2.min_tx > 8
        AND t1.date_time = t2.latest_tx;
```

Now, one can use the [UNION](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0163.htm?lang=en) statement to combine the result sets:

```
SELECT  t1.rx, 
        t1.tx, 
        t1.date_time
FROM    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  rx, 
                MAX(tx) AS max_tx, 
                MIN(tx)  AS min_tx 
        FROM    table1 
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t2 ON t1.rx = t2.rx
WHERE   8 BETWEEN t2.min_tx AND t2.max_tx
        AND t1.tx < 8
UNION
SELECT  t1.rx, 
        t1.tx, 
        t1.date_time
FROM    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  rx, 
                MIN(tx) AS min_tx,
                MAX(date_time) AS latest_tx
        FROM    table1 
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t2 ON t1.rx = t2.rx
WHERE   t2.min_tx > 8
        AND t1.date_time = t2.latest_tx;
```